# Selecionar combo box ou dropdownlist google maps

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, google-maps

Galera estou usando google maps em uma aplicação esta salvando tudo ok, mas surgiu uma duvida como poderia selecionar um combo box por Estado, e todos os registros que esta na minha tabela com aquele estado aparecer no mapa?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei enviar um objeto em json, ele ate lista os estado no combo, mas não consegue enviar a latitude e longitude que esta no banco para o mapa.

Comment: Seria interessante mais detalhes, como por exemplo o tipo de registro e como gostaria que eles aparecessem.

Comment: Luis santos acabei editando minha pergunta, tenho minha tela de cadastro que captura a longitude e latitude junto com o cadastro manual nome estado e ocorrência do navio afundado, mas na index não consigo achar uma maneira de quando selecionar aquele estado pegar todos os registros vinculados nele, na query esta ok, não consigo enviar as coordenadas.